# Загрузка нескольких ядер процессора, при консольной команде с pipe

Tags: windows, cmd, pipes

Запускаю в консоли команду, увязывающую последовательную обработку 4 приложениями.

```
balabolka.exe | sox.exe | soundstretch.exe | lame.exe
```

Диспетчер задач показывает, что суммарная загрузка от всех приложений равна ~25% на 4-ядерном процессоре. То есть задействовано только 1 ядро. Между приложениями загрузка распределена примерно 55/15/7/23.
Как распараллелить обработку? Скорость должна ограничиваться возможностями самого требовательного из приложений. Ускорение должно получится примерно в 2 раза.

Comment: Раньше т. е. в ms-dos это работало последовательно, через временные файлы, боюсь, что всё так и осталось. А у вас есть возможность собрать обработку в одну программу?

Comment: @PavelGridin Питоновский `subprocess.Popen` не помог. Даже запуск в pythonw, хоть и создает по консоли conhost для каждого приложения, суммарная нагрузка все равно ограничена. В собранном варианте уже есть, но хотелось вернутся к более штатному и конфигурируемому варианту.

Comment: Есть хорошая вещь для распараллеливания поточных вычислений, но она для C++ https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506068

Comment: хотя вроде есть и для питона https://pypi.org/project/tbb4py

Comment: @PavelGridin Не понял, как векторизация, параллелизм независимых задач, поможет для связанных *системным пайплайном* зависимых задач.

Comment: это применимо, только если есть возможность отказаться от системного pipeline

Comment: @PavelGridin Абсолютно непредсказуемое поведение. Попробовал другие конвейеры из области обработки аудио, в разных сочетаниях. Некоторые загружают по прежнему 25, другие 35 и даже 45%. Причем второй образец, запущенный в `pythonW` с `Popen(['worker.bat'], shell=True)` неожиданно выдал 55%, где одно из приложений уперлось в эталонные 25%. На этом, вопрос снимается как неоднозначный и не имеющий однозначного решения. Спасибо за идеи.